# How to stop the loop if the value is not found?

Tags: javascript, foreach

1 - I need to stop the loop and return an error if the 'grid_id' is not found in the variationsDB array

2 - If found, it takes the 'variation_id' and checks if it exists in the variations array

In this second case, I also need to stop the loop and return an error if the 'variation_id' is not found in the variations array

```
const grids = [{ "grid_id": 1 }, { "grid_id": 2 }]

const variationsDB = [
    {
        "variation_id": 3,
        "grid_id": 1
    },
    {
        "variation_id": 7,
        "grid_id": 2
    }
]

const variations = [{ "variation_id": 3 }, { "variation_id": 7 }]

const filter = (a, b, key) => {
    const array = []

    a.forEach((x) => {
        b.forEach((y) => {
            if (x[key] === y[key]) {
                array.push(y)
            }
        })
    })

    return array
}

const filterA = filter(grids, variationsDB, 'grid_id')
const filterB = filter(filterA, variations, 'variation_id')

console.log(filterB)
// [{ "variation_id": 3 }, { "variation_id": 7 }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just checking if the resulting array is empty or not sounds like it'd be enough:

```
const filterA = filter(grids, variationsDB, 'grid_id')
if (!filterA.length) {
    throw new Error('No matches found for grid_id');
}
const filterB = filter(filterA, variations, 'variation_id')
if (!filterB.length) {
    throw new Error('No matches found for variation_id');
}
console.log(filterB)
```

Your code's computational complexity can be reduced from `O(n ^ 2)` to `O(n)` by organizing the first array of items into a Set of values first:

```js
const grids = [{ "grid_id": 1 }, { "grid_id": 2 }]

const variationsDB = [
    {
        "variation_id": 3,
        "grid_id": 1
    },
    {
        "variation_id": 7,
        "grid_id": 2
    }
]

const variations = [{ "variation_id": 3 }, { "variation_id": 7 }]

const validate = (a, b, key) => {
    const aValues = new Set(a.map(aItem => aItem[key]));
    for (const bItem of b) {
      if (!aValues.has(bItem[key])) {
        throw new Error('No match found for', key, bItem[key]);
      }
    }
}

validate(grids, variationsDB, 'grid_id')
validate(variationsDB, variations, 'variation_id')
console.log(variations)
```

Comment: I did a quick test here and did not return the error when one of the items in the array ( variationsDB ) was not found in the next array ( variations ). https://gist.github.com/jonathansilva/4ba39e8ae93b21237b6e80b769e9325b#file-test-js-L12

Comment: Oh, you want to check that *all* values exist, not that *at least one* value exists? Simple enough

Comment: If at least one of these values does not exist, return an error... Step 1 (array grids) ... Step 2 (array variationsDB) ... Step 3 (array variations). In this order

Comment: The values of the 'grids' array, always exist hahahaha. This check would be in the other 2 arrays

Comment: You always have to compare something against something else - so its `grids` against `variationsDB`, then the `variationsDB` against the `variations`. So 2 validation steps.

Comment: Yes, but how to do it in the least complex way ?